# How to Open file on hard drive with associated app using PInvoke

Tags: silverlight, pinvoke

Here is what I need to do:

From Silverlight App, the End User needs to be able to open and view a file using the associated app, such as a PDF.

Silverlight 5 supports PInvoke, so I am trying to do this through PInvoke.

At first I thought that OpenFile in kernel32.dll would achieve this, but I have tried and it doesn't actually open up the app like I thought it would.

So is there a PInvoke call that will do this?

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(
    IntPtr hwnd,
    string lpOperation,
    string lpFile,
    string lpParameters,
    string lpDirectory,
    ShowCommands nShowCmd
);
```

(credit to Hans for answer.)

Comment: No, only ShellExecuteEx() knows how to use file associations.

Comment: Better use `ShellExecuteEx` so that you can, amongst other things, deal with errors properly.